# Analysis problem: Show that$ f(x)$ is less or equal than$ g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Analysis problem:

**Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable on $ \mathbb R$. Suppose that $f(0)=g(0)$ and that $f' (x)$ is less or equal than $g' (x)$ for all $x$ greater or equal than $0$ Show that $f(x)$ is less or equal than$g(x)$ for all $x$ greater or equal than $0$.**

Is my proof correct?

I am trying to use the Generalized Mean Value Theorem:

[image: Generalized Mean Value Theorem]

As $f$and g are differentiable on$ \mathbb R$, $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $ \mathbb R$ and we can use the Generalized Value Theorem. Using the starting condition $f(0)=g(0)$, we have that for any b that is greater than$ 0$, exist a $c$ element of $(0,b)$ such that

$f' (c) g(b) =  g' (c) f(b)$

By the starting conditions,

$f' (x) $is less or equal than$g' (x)$ for all $x$ greater or equal than $0$

Therefore, $f(b)$ is less or equal than $g(b)$ for any b element of $(0, b)$

As $b$ is any number bigger than$ 0$

**$f(x)$ is less or equal than $g(x)$ for any $x$ greater or bigger than$ 0$. Q.E.D.**

Comment: I think it is fine.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you for your support and your thoughts!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Or you can use the simple MVT for the function $f - g$.

Comment: The key point in your argument is to go from $f'(c)g(b)=g'(c)f(b)$ to $f(b)\leq g(b)$. I don't see how you achieve that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for your help! if f' is less or equal than g', then f(b) has to be less or equal than g(b) to keep the equality. What do you think?

Comment: @dxiv I like that idea. Brilliant! I did not think about that possibility. Thank you!

Comment: @Beginner: $0<2$ and $0\times(-1)=2\times0$. But you cannot conclude that $0<-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see how you conclude from 
$
f'(c)g(b)=g'(c)f(b)
$
and $f'(c)\leq g'(c)$ that $f(b)\leq g(b)$. For instance, $0<2$ and $0\times (-1) = 2\times 0$, but you cannot conclude that $0\leq-1$.

As mentioned by dxiv, a proof can be achieved by using the Mean Value Theorem, applied to the function $g-f$: given any $x\geq0$, there exists $c$ with $0\leq c\leq x$ and $$g(x)-f(x)=g(x)-f(x)-(g(0)-f(0))=(g'(c)-f'(c))\,(x-0)\geq0.$$

It is also worth mentioning that the "direct way":
$$
f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\leq\int_0^xg'(t)\,dt=g(x)
$$
doesn't work in general, because it is not true in general that $f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt$; this requires $f$ to be [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191268/absolutely-continuous-functions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative)).

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant comment! You taught me a lot with your explanation why my reasoning was wrong!

Answer (score 5):

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x);x\in [0,\infty)$

$h^{'}(x)=f^{'}(x)-g^{'}(x)\le 0\implies h$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)\implies h(x)\le h(0)\forall x\in [0,\infty)\implies f(x)\le g(x)$

Comment: Beautiful proof! Thank you for your teachings!

Comment: You are welcome